# How to fix this route configuration? Configured route returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to define a route configuration which will allow an optional 'region' in the following URLs, all of which will default to the home page:

```
/uk/home // where the 'uk' parameter can be either 'uk' or 'us'
/uk      // where the 'uk' parameter can be either 'uk' or 'us'
/        // in this case, I just want the region to default to 'uk'
```

The results I'm getting are not ideal though. the first one (`/uk/home`), and the third one (`/`) both work, but the second one (`/uk`), returns 404.

The configurations are defined as:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{region}/{controller}",
            new { region = "^UK|US$" },
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "{region}",
            new { region = "^UK|US$" },
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            //"{region}",
            "",
            new {region = "UK", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

What do i need to do to ensure that all 3 urls will default to the home page, with the empty URL defaulting the region to 'uk'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Region",
    "{region}/{controller}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    new { region = "^UK|US$" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", region = "UK" }
);
```